# Homomorphism of circle group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Related to my previous question, I would like to know if I approached the following correctly:

Consider the group of symmetries of a circle denoted by $D_\infty$. Let $SD_\infty$ denote the subgroup of $D_\infty$ consisting of only rotations.

Let $\phi: D_\infty \rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ be defined by $\phi(x)=$ $1$, if $x$ is a rotation and $-1$ if $x$ is a reflection.

**Question:** Is $\phi$ a homomorphism?

**My attempt:**
We need to show that $f(x)f(y) = f(xy)$ for any $x, y \in G$.

We prove this by cases:

(i) $x$ and $y$ are rotations. Then, $xy$ is also a rotation. 
So, $f(x)f(y) = 1 * 1 = 1 = f(xy)$.

(ii) $x$ and $y$ are reflections. Then, $xy$ is a rotation. 
So, $f(x)f(y) = -1 * -1 = 1 = f(xy)$.

(iii) $x$ is a reflection and $y$ is a rotation. Then, $xy$ is also a reflection. 
So, $f(x)f(y) = -1 * 1 = -1 = f(xy)$.

(iv) $x$ is a rotation and $y$ is a reflection. Then, $xy$ is also a reflection. 
So, $f(x)f(y) = -1 * 1 = -1 = f(xy)$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a note: $D_{\infty}$ is usually the notation for the infinite dihedral group, which is not the same as the group of symmetries of the circle (the infinite dihedral group is countable, and the circle has an uncountable number of symmetries).